# Pairwise Row Matrix Multiplication in R

Tags: r, matrix

Hi guys I have a question regarding an matrix operation in R. I have a data set like the one bellow:

## Sample Data:

```
d <- data.frame(id=c(2,3,4,5,6,6,8,11,11,11,12,12,12),author=c("FN","VM","VA","FK","VM","SM","FK","FK","VB","VA","FK","VB","VA"))
d
   id author
1   2     FN
2   3     VM
3   4     VA
4   5     FK
5   6     VM
6   6     SM
7   8     FK
8  11     FK
9  11     VB
10 11     VA
11 12     FK
12 12     VB
13 12     VA
```

## 1)Created an Incidence Matrix:

```
> m <- xtabs(~author+id,d)
> m
      id
author 2 3 4 5 6 8 11 12
    FK 0 0 0 1 0 1  1  1
    FN 1 0 0 0 0 0  0  0
    SM 0 0 0 0 1 0  0  0
    VA 0 0 1 0 0 0  1  1
    VB 0 0 0 0 0 0  1  1
    VM 0 1 0 0 1 0  0  0
```

What I want to do is to generate pair combinations from the author list, in column 2, by multiplying each row. For instance for the pair FK-VA, its corresponding rows in the incidence matrix are this:

```
FK 0 0 0 1 0 1  1  1
VA 0 0 1 0 0 0  1  1
```

The expected outcome in my matrix should produce a multiplication by each element of the rows:

```
FK-VA (0*0),(0*0),(0*1),(1*0),(0*0),(1*0),(1*1),(1*1)
FK-VA   0   0   0   0   0   1   1
```

## 2)Expected outcome would be this matrix(m):

```
FK  FN  0   0   0   0   0   0   0
FK  SM  0   0   0   0   0   0   0
FK  VA  0   0   0   0   0   1   1
FK  VB  0   0   0   0   0   1   1
FK  VM  0   0   0   0   0   0   0
FN  SM  0   0   0   0   0   0   0
FN  VA  0   0   0   0   0   0   0
FN  VB  0   0   0   0   0   0   0
FN  VM  0   0   0   0   0   0   0
SM  VA  0   0   0   0   0   0   0
SM  VB  0   0   0   0   0   0   0
SM  VM  0   0   0   1   0   0   0
VA  VB  0   0   0   0   0   1   1
VA  VM  0   0   0   0   0   0   0
VB  VM  0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

## 3) Delete Empty rows.

As you can see I need help for the steps 2 and 3.

Thank you

Mario

Comment: Are you sure the expected matrix is correct?

Comment: I did it manually in excel, possible that contain some mistakes, but the idea as I explained, is create pairs by the "author" column, an multiply  the rows. Generate a new matrix with this pairs. At least the dimensions of the example matrix are right.

Comment: I got a similar matrix but the values were not the same as your expected one.

Comment: can you explain me the procedure?

Comment: I posted a solution, but I am not sure how  you want to merge the id when the pairwise author list is created.  I used one column as reference.

Comment: Wouldn't the last entry would be `VB VM`?

Comment: Dear @akrun, you are right about the VB-VM, I have an extra question, let me know if you can address it here, or do you need me to open another post. I'm using this command "CL <- colSums(res1[,-(1:2)])" to generate a row of the sum of each column. Further, I rest minus one by each element of that vector, "CL <- CL -1", and replacing all the negative values by zero "CL[ CL<1 ] <- 0". Finally I want to divide each row of "rest1" by CL, using this command "rest2 <- res1[,-(1:2)] %*% diag(1/CL)". But it's striking me with this error: "Error in res1[, -(1:2)] %*% diag(1/CL)". Can you help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be this helps

```
indx <- combn(dimnames(m)$author,2)
res <- cbind(t(indx), as.data.frame(do.call(rbind,
       lapply(split(indx, col(indx)), function(x) m[x[1],]*m[x[2],]))))

colnames(res)[1:2] <- paste0('author', 1:2)
head(res,3)
#  author1 author2 2 3 4 5 6 8 11 12
#1      FK      FN 0 0 0 0 0 0  0  0
#2      FK      SM 0 0 0 0 0 0  0  0
#3      FK      VA 0 0 0 0 0 0  1  1
```

Or

```
  cbind(t(indx),as.data.frame(t(combn(dimnames(m)$author,2,
                           FUN=function(x) m[x[1],] * m[x[2],]))))
```

If you want to subset the rows that have at least some value other than `0`

```
res1 <- res[!!rowSums(res[,-(1:2)]),]
```

#### Update

For the `sum`, you can do `rowSums`

```
res$Sum <- rowSums(res[,-(1:2)])
head(res,3)
 #  author1 author2 2 3 4 5 6 8 11 12 Sum
 #1      FK      FN 0 0 0 0 0 0  0  0   0
 #2      FK      SM 0 0 0 0 0 0  0  0   0
 #3      FK      VA 0 0 0 0 0 0  1  1   2
```

#### Update2

Regarding the second question of dividing `res1` by `CL`

```
 CL <- colSums(res1[,-(1:2)])
 CL <- CL-1
 CL[ CL<1 ] <- 0
 res1[-(1:2)]/CL[col(res1[-(1:2)])]
```

#### Update3

Regarding the new dataset,

```
   d <- read.csv('AuthorsRevised.csv', stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
   m <- xtabs(~Authors+ID,d)
   indx <- combn(dimnames(m)$Authors,2)
   dim(indx)
   #[1]      2 435711

   res <- cbind(t(indx), as.data.frame(do.call(rbind,
        lapply(split(indx, col(indx)), function(x) m[x[1],]*m[x[2],]))))

   colnames(res)[1:2] <- paste0('author', 1:2)

   dim(res)
   #[1] 435711    534
   res[1:3,1:3]
   #    author1          author2 1
   #1 Abe S.-i.    Achterberg W. 0
   #2 Abe S.-i. Adebowale B.O.A. 0
   #3 Abe S.-i.        Aghion P. 0
```

Another option if you just want the `sum` would be

```
   t1 <- crossprod(table(d))
   t1[upper.tri(t1, diag=TRUE)] <- NA
   library(reshape2)
   res1 <- melt(t1, na.rm=TRUE)[,c(2:1,3)]
```

Comment: Your command is good for producing the pairs, but the values are not right. I'll give you an example for FK  VA, the values of the incidence matrix are this:
FK 0 0 0 1 0 1  1  1
VA 0 0 1 0 0 0  1  1
The row multiplication in my expected outcome, should only take into consideration the overlapping values of 1. i.e.
FK  VA  0   0   0   0   1   1   1
I, don't know if I'm explaining myself well.

Comment: Dear @akrun, now its working quite right! Just one more tip, If you don't mind, I would like to sum up each row in a new column, for instance
FK      VA 0 0 0 0 0 0  1  1
Sum(Fk-VA) = 2
And do this for each pair, Thanks a lot!

Comment: Dear @akrun, all you recommendations worked fine for my sample data. However, when I run it using my database(https://www.dropbox.com/s/h1py0qi047cuymv/AuthorsRevised.csv?dl=0), this command "res <- cbind(t(indx), as.data.frame(do.call(rbind, lapply(split(indx, col(indx)), function(x) m[x[1],]*m[x[2],]))))" freeze my computer. Any suggestions?

Comment: @MarioGS It could be because your dataset is really big.

Comment: I think you are right, but, do you have any suggestions for fixing it?

Comment: @MarioGS It did work for me though, Please check the update.  One option would be to use some clusters if the data is bigger than the one you showed.

Comment: Dear @akrun, I incorporated all your commands of "Update 2" and  "Update 3" in this Script (https://www.dropbox.com/s/quc66xzin25gh5b/Weighted6.R?dl=0). But, still freezing my computer, I also tried in another one and it's the same... I was wondering, if you can send me the outcome of this script in a csv file. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @MarioGS  Here is the dropbox link. I hope the link works. /home/arunksa111/Dropbox/Public/Link to Mario.csv

Comment: Dear @akrum, could you please send me the full address of the link?

Comment: @MarioGS When I clicked on the copy link, it is the one I am getting.

Comment: @MarioGS If you have some site where I can upload it, let me know.  It is >250 MB.

Comment: Its weird, it should not be that heavy, something its not working.... Maybe it is not deleting the zero rows, or something else... Here is an open folder in my google drive: https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0Bwrb1f2EpJo_VHhTQmN0bVI5RUE&usp=sharing

Comment: @MarioGS  I did share the file there.  Please check.

Comment: Dear @akrum, the file is so big that I cannot even open it. I suspect that the code is not erasing the zero rows... I will expect this file to have the same number of rows as the edge list in my network, "https://www.dropbox.com/s/f3e32c24fyx91vv/Edge-list.csv?dl=0". But it is not the case, something is wrong, are you using my script?

Comment: @MarioGS  I am using the script as in `Update3`

Comment: @akrum, that is the problem, in a previous comment I posted that I assemble a new script including the updates 2 and 3, together. Could you please run this script "https://www.dropbox.com/s/quc66xzin25gh5b/Weighted6.R?dl=0".

Comment: @MarioGS In the script, the `CL` is saved.  So, `res` or `res1` is not you wanted? Then what is the need for all the other codes, `res3` etc.  My point is that getting to `CL` was faster while `res` or `res1` computation was slow.  I am guessing that your system should also process that CL computation.